# Summing Python Tuple Subsets ((1,john), (2, joey))=(3, john + joey)

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to add all the tuples inside a subset together.

so far I have:

```
list(itertools.combinations(((1, 'aa'), (2, 'bb'), (3, 'cc'), (4, 'dd'),
(5, 'ee'), (6, 'ff'), (7, 'gg'), (8, 'hh')), 6))
```

which produces:

```
((1, 'aa'), (2, 'bb'), (5, 'ee'), (6, 'ff'), (7, 'gg'), (8, 'hh')), 
((1, 'aa'), (3, 'cc'), (4, 'dd'), (5, 'ee'), (6, 'ff'), (7, 'gg')),
```

but I then want to add all the numerical values together and nonnumerical values together such as:

```
(29, 'aa'+'bb'+'ee'+'ff'+'gg'+'hh')
```

I then want to sort them in ascending order with a maximum.  What took me one line in mathematica is driving me crazy in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely do this in one (and a bit) line in Python if you're comfortable with list comprehensions/generator expressions:

```
combs = list(itertools.combinations(
    ((1, 'aa'), (2, 'bb'), (3, 'cc'), (4, 'dd'),
     (5, 'ee'), (6, 'ff'), (7, 'gg'), (8, 'hh')), 
    6
))
sums = [
    (sum(n for n, text in comb), ''.join(text for n, text in comb)) 
    for comb in combs
]

# Will sort by number first, then text, by default
sorted(sums)
Out[8]: 
[(21, 'aabbccddeeff'),
 (22, 'aabbccddeegg'),
 (23, 'aabbccddeehh'),
 (23, 'aabbccddffgg'),
 (24, 'aabbccddffhh'),
 (24, 'aabbcceeffgg'),
 (25, 'aabbccddgghh'),
 (25, 'aabbcceeffhh'),
 # Etc.
```

Comment: Don't forget to sort it :)